# "Unable to find drag handle" mistake in react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I have a list of cards that want to **drag and drop**. I want the user could drag and drop by pressing  on the specific place  (div) on the card (not the whole card).  I transfer this div to the child component and add  **{...provided.dragHandleProps}** on this div. Everything works ok, but I get mistakes in console, that **Unable to find drag handle**. How can I fix this problem?

```
 const posts = (
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.dragDrop}>
        <Droppable droppableId="dragCards">
          {(provided) => (
            <div ref={provided.innerRef}>
              {cards.map((item, index) => {
                return (                    
                      <Draggable draggableId={item.key} index={index}>
                        {(provided) => (
                          <div                    
                            ref={provided.innerRef}
                            {...provided.draggableProps}
                          >
                            <Cards                                                              
                              dragChip={
                                <div {...provided.dragHandleProps}>
                                  {dragChip}
                                </div>
                              }  />
                          </div>
                        )}
                      </Draggable>                       
                );
              })}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </div>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </DragDropContext>
    );
```

And this is **div**, that I transfer to the child component.

```
 const dragChip = (
      <div >
        drag me
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: Can you try destructuring  {...provided.dragHandleProps} in parent <div/> of <Cards/> 
  
<div  
      ref={provided.innerRef}
     {...provided.draggableProps}
     {...provided.dragHandleProps}   
  >


Let me know, if it helps

Comment: Shubham Jajoo, I tried to do it, but I can drag and drop the whole card in any place I click it. And I need to drag and drop card only if I click on specific place.

Answer (score 1):

You can spread the props in the div inside the drag chip component.
And if you want to conditionally drag and drop, then you can use the `isDragDisabled` prop of Draggable component

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your  `<Draggable>` needs a key.

**Before**
`<Draggable draggableId={item.key} index={index}>`

**After**
`<Draggable key={item.key} draggableId={item.key} index={index}>`

https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1673#issuecomment-571293508